# HNews "ask section" page scraping Python script

Tags: python, web-scraping

Here is a small script I wrote to get the HNews ask section and display them without using a web browser.  I'm just looking for feedback on how to improve my style/coding logic/overall code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

'''This script gets the headlines from hacker news ask section'''

import urllib2
import HTMLParser
import re

class HNParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
def __init__(self):
    HTMLParser.HTMLParser.__init__(self)
    self.data=[]
    self.recording=0

def handle_starttag(self, tag, attribute):
    if tag!='a':
        return
    elif self.recording:
        self.recording +=1
        return
    for name, value in attribute:
        if name=='href' and value[0]=='i':
            break
    else:
        return
    self.recording=1

def handle_endtag(self, tag):
    if tag=='a' and self.recording:
        self.recording-=1

def handle_data(self, data):
    if self.recording:
        self.data.append(data)


HOST='http://news.ycombinator.com/ask'
parser=HNParser()
f=urllib2.urlopen(HOST)
rawHTML=f.read()
parser.feed(rawHTML)
i=0
for items in parser.data:
    try:
        print parser.data[2*i]
        i+=1
    except IndexError:
        break
 parser.close()
```

Comment: You'll almost definitely get someone who points out that your indenting is incorrect ... wait that was me! Just check the preview before you submit it so that the code section looks the same as your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would modify your script. Comments are inline. This version is PEP8-PyLint-PyFlakes approved. ;-)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

'''This script gets the headlines from hacker news ask section'''

import urllib2
import HTMLParser
# remove unused imports


class HNParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):

    # use class-level attribute instead of "magic" strings.
    tag_name = 'a'

    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.data = []
        self.recording = 0

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attribute):

        if tag != self.tag_name:
            return

        # clearer implicit loop, with no "break"
        if not any(name == 'href' and value.startswith('item')
                for name, value in attribute):
            return

        # no need to check if self.recording == 0, because in that case setting
        # self.recording = 1 is equivalent to incrementing self.recording!
        self.recording += 1

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == self.tag_name and self.recording:
            self.recording -= 1

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.recording:
            self.data.append(data)


def main():
    HOST = 'http://news.ycombinator.com/ask'
    parser = HNParser()
    f = urllib2.urlopen(HOST)
    rawHTML = f.read()
    parser.feed(rawHTML)
    try:
        # use fancy list indexing and omit last "Feature Request" link
        for item in parser.data[:-1:2]:
            print item
    finally:
        # close the parser even if exception is raised
        parser.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I’m not convinced that the generic `tag_name` is more readable than `'a'`, on the contrary. I’m all for using an attribute here, but give it a proper name. The context suggets that it should be called `starttag` – or maybe `linktag`. Also, the `try … finally: parser.close()` should be replaced with a `with` block.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `HTMLParser.HTMLParser.__init__(self)` you should write `super(HTMLParser.HTMLParser, self).__init__()`

`urllib2` and `HTMLParser`, though included with Python, are very limited. [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [lxml + cssselect](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html) are more powerful. With them, your script can be written as

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring
content = requests.get('https://news.ycombinator.com/ask').content
html_doc = fromstring(content)
# Select all title links & ignore 
links = html_doc.cssselect('.title > a[href^=item]')
print '\n'.join(link.text for link in links)
```